# How to make time_ago_in_words show right value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I explicitly state in my Production.rb that I want UTC with:

```
# Timezone Set
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Then I log into my production machine and run the production console (machine defaults to +4 Mowscow Time).. I get the following output:

```
$ Time.now
=> 2012-02-04 20:52:32 +0400 
$ Time.zone.now
 => Sat, 04 Feb 2012 16:52:43 UTC +00:00
```

The value of Time_ago_in_words is always +4 .. if I post something 'now'.. it shows as '4 hours'.... that counts down to 0 after 4 hours.. then starts being negative (i.e. 1 hour ago)....  How do I get this to display correctly?

=================

After a too many hours trying to figure out how to do this.. I finally figured out just after posting this :-|  I had to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

And set my timezone to UTC there.. now Time.now outputs the UTC instead of Moscow.. I'll leave this here for anyone else that runs into this.

Comment: man, post it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with @nash Post that as the answer

Comment: Went ahead and did that, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by those commenting, here is the solution that allowed me to get this to work:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

And set my timezone to UTC there.. now Time.now outputs the UTC instead of Moscow.